# SharePoint Discussion Board View to show one discussion thread

Tags: discussion-board, spview

I need to show a particular thread that resides in a discussion board.  I am currently trying to use SPViews.

The following is my code

```
            SPView threadedView = discussionBoard.Views["Threaded"];
        threadedView.Title = "Comments WebPart";

        //threadedView.Query = query.ToString();
        threadedView.RenderAsHtml();
```

however this view is giving me all the discussion threads in the discussion board not a single thread which is needed.  tried also to set a query for the view but was useless. can anyone help pls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should treat Discussions as Folders and Threads as plain items. Basically the content types are Discussion (which inherits from Folder) and Message.
Afterwards the best is to use SPQuery to retrieve the Items or simple GetItemById on the list to retrieve your item.

The Message has a field as follows `<Field ID="{7662cd2c-f069-4dba-9e35-082cf976e170}" Type="Note" RichText="TRUE" RichTextMode="FullHtml" IsolateStyles="TRUE" NumLines="15" Name="Body" DisplayName="$Resources:core,camlid2;" Sortable="FALSE" AllowDeletion="FALSE" SourceID="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3" StaticName="Body">
      </Field>`
which returns the full content of it. Just retrieve it.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 0):

If this is in a webpart or usercontrol and you want to show the view in an aspx page, then you just need this code and then pass in the url parameter ?RootFolder=... and this will give you all the messages under this discussion.