# Threaded view discussion board to be displayed in custom webpart sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a threaded discussion board and i need to programmatically display those disussions and replies in my custom webpart.

please help

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the below given post. It will help you to understand the base concept of using discussion board.

[SharePoint Discussion Board View to show one discussion thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27016/sharepoint-discussion-board-view-to-show-one-discussion-thread)

Thanks